# Detecting when jQuery's hide() method is fired on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is it possible to detect when jQuery has fired it's `.hide()` method on an element?

I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/Snvgr/) binding to the `hide` event on such an element:

```js
$('div').bind('hide', function(){
        alert("Hidden");
    })
```

but the alert doesn't display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by overriding JQuery's hide method:

```
var oldHide = $.fn.hide;

$.fn.hide = function() {
    alert("Hidden");
    oldHide.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

...as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/Snvgr/1/).

Comment: why would you do that?
what if a plugin that you didn't write is expecting hide to work in a certain way?

Comment: @David Meister: To know why, you'd have to query the question author. But it's important that your override still 'works the same way'. In other languages they call this 'abiding by the contract'.

Comment: but throwing an alert really doesn't "work the same way" as it halts the operation of the browser until the user responds..

i think we need more information from the OP

Comment: @David Throwing the alert is just a simple way to demonstrate that the method works.

Answer (score 1):

all the time? or just for debugging?

you could just use the call back function to write something to the log.

```
$( '#my-id' ).hide( duration, function(){ console.log( 'fired!' ); } );
```